# acf - wordpress - wrapper attributes

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

has the option to specify 'wrapper attributes' in the 'advanced custom fields' wordpress plugin been removed?  I have downloaded version 4.4.3 and the option is not there when I create a new 'text' field.  As per the documentation, the text field should offer this [attribute](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-settings/).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapper attributes are part of ACF 5.x. You would need the Pro version for that. Additionally, all ACF documentation on their site is geared towards Pro.

See full spec for Pro here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/

That said, the wrapper itself is for back-end display.

Comment: ok, thanks for answering my question.  Yep, I figured the wrapper attribute will save me a small amount of time but not a must have.

Comment: Wow, admin only. Thanks